# text books - studying

Tags: books

Is there some sort of source/website that states all the required textbooks for a particular subject? For instance, I'm intrigued too learn about certain subjects however I am no graduate or anything, so attempting to enrol would be pointless, but I do wish to study in my own time and with the correct textbooks. Does anyone have any pointers? If they could offer any advice, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: What "the correct textbooks" are depends a lot on whom you ask to. There is a bazillion textbooks around for every undergraduate subject.

Comment: While the question can be better worded, I don't see why it should be closed. The question asks for general directions in finding appropriate textbooks, which is certainly on topic and not opinion based (i.e., it is not asking *which* textbook is better).

Comment: Thanks, mate. I'm just attempting to begin a navigation through a maelstrom, hoping I could collect some information before I charted my course. Some people can't grasp my 'simple folk' mindset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Professors publish their syllabi online. You could try browsing courses on the subject you’re interested in, picking the course you like the most and look up the textbooks the Professor requires. That way you can have your suitable textbooks without any need to enroll, and you’re free to study in your own time.

Comment: How would one find these syllabi? Google the subject and navigate through which colleges offer them?

Comment: That would be a perfect way to do it. Say you’re interested in thermodynamics, you could google “thermodynamics syllabus”, or find a physics degree and look through its thermodynamics course, or find a college and look directly on their site. You can do whatever you’re most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Many major universities offer open access to all, most or some of their courses content. Some of the prominent examples are MIT OpenCourseWare, Harvard Online Learning and Open Yale Courses. They all have courses in a variety of fields, and will list at least the reading requirements for the course, including the textbook and sometimes the specific chapters and sections. Many courses also offer specific lecture notes, video or audio lectures, assignments and exams.